# Mysql and PHP: Get the values from the same day in infinite scroll

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table with many fields, one of them is the date (format yyyy/mm/dd). I want to make a query that gets all entries from the days before e make it keep going down. I'm going to try to explain it better with examples.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    date, 
    site, 
    url, 
FROM links 
WHERE online    = "yes"  AND 
      data     <= ?      AND 
      category != ?      AND 
ORDER BY date DESC, clicks DESC
LIMIT 200
```

The array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014/02/25
    [1] => Adult
)
```

Problem is, I'm don't want to set a limit. Since the limit would be all the fields from the same date.

I can't set the field `date = yyyy/mm/dd` because I'm using a script that has an infinite scroll style, so I don't know which date it's gonna be. Besides, I don't have data from all days, so it's gonna fail at some point.

So, is there a way to get the values from the same date without sending it using PHP? For example, a Mysql value set inside the query, or something.

Comment: If you just want all entries from days before day X, then can't you just add something like WHERE date < yyyy/mm/dd and substitute that date with X

Comment: But I need only the fields from that day, not from other days. This way you told me it's gonna get all the fields from all the days before. I need exactly one day before, 3 days before, something like this. I don't know how I can do that, because I don't know which date is gonna be inside the table.

Comment: Oh ok. Then something like this, (date < CURDATE() AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAYS)). You can substitute the '3' in PHP for whatever variable you need. You should look up Date and Time functions in SQL

Comment: Is there a way to set a variable from one field and then use that value as a statement? For example `set @date = "theValue";` and then use it in the query like `date = @date`.

Comment: yes you can declare local variables in the SQL if you want, read more about that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html)